# How to Pass array of Dictionary to a .NET method

Tags: c#, ios

I am trying to send Array of dictionary to a .NET webService method which takes List<> as a parameter. But I receive exception for the same. Method header name in .NET server is

```
public int SaveCustomerDetails(string cardNumber, string loginId,
    List<CustomerFieldDetails> customerDetailsParams)
```

and my array of dictionary is as

```
(
    {
    FieldType = TEXT;
    FieldValue = abcd;
    name = "customer_name";
},
    {
    FieldType = TEXT;
    FieldValue = "middlename";
    name = "middle_name";
},
    {
    FieldType = TEXT;
    FieldValue = "lastname";
    name = "last_name";
})
```

Kindly help me out for this. Thanks in advance.

I am using SoapEngine for this

```
SoapEngine *soap = [[SoapEngine alloc] init];
[soap setValue:self.customerFieldDetails forKey:@"customerDetailsParams"];
[soap requestToSaveCustomerDetailsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSInteger statusCode, NSDictionary *dict) {

    } failure:^(NSError *error) {

    }];
```

Comment: Could you provide the code for posting data to server?

Answer (score 0):

Array in JSON is formated using the symbols [ and ]. In your example (it is not full) I didn't see the square brackets but you use round brackets. Also you are using = symbol instead of : between field name and its value.
So, the correct array of objects should be:

```
"customerDetailsParams": [
    {
    FieldType : TEXT,
    FieldValue : abcd,
    name : "customer_name",
},
    {
    FieldType : TEXT,
    FieldValue : "middlename",
    name : "middle_name",
},
    {
    FieldType : TEXT,
    FieldValue : "lastname",
    name : "last_name",
}]
```

Comment: please see my next post

Comment: self.customerFieldDetails - what is the type of this - NSArray or NSDictionary?

Comment: its the same array which i have posted in.

Comment: do you have a internal structure of CustomerFieldDetails .NET object? Your customerFieldDetails is smth like this: NSDictionary *d= [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:.....];
    NSArray *customerFieldDetails = [NSArray arrayWithObject:d]; ??

Comment: yes CustomerFieldDetails have an internal structure